# Install Windows 10 with UEFI from USB

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, lenovo-laptop, bootable-media

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a Lenovo U410 having recently replaced the 32GB mSATA Cache with a larger SSD to be used as a primary system drive.

I've created USB install media with Rufus using the 'GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer' option, and FAT32 File system.

However the USB isn't recognised as a bootable device unless I change the boot mode to 'Legacy Support', and in doing so Windows doesn't install in UEFI mode.

Is it possible to use UEFI in these circumstances?

Comment: Was it prepared with a 64-bit Windows ISO? Is there a `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` in the USB?

Comment: I'll have to double check the USB this evening for that file but yes I'm pretty certain it was a 64-bit ISO

Comment: Why are you switching to legacy mode if you want to install in UEFI mode, Legeacy would mean a MBR partition instead of GPT

Comment: That was just a sanity check to confirm that it was the UEFI boot mode which was causing the USB not to be read.

Comment: @TomYan I've confirmed that there's a \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI on the USB